# How do I fix this error when deploying a contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment

The error is "The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."

When I clicked on "debug" on remix, it points to the constructor. This is the constructor:

```
constructor () {
    _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
    IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);       // binance PANCAKE V2
    //IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);     // binance PANCAKE V1
    //IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);     // Ethereum mainnet, Ropsten, Rinkeby, Görli, and Kovan      
    uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
    uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
    _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
    _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
    _isExcludedFromReward[address(this)] = true;
    _isExcludedFromFee[BURN_ADDRESS] = true;
    _isExcludedFromReward[BURN_ADDRESS] = true;
    emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
}
```

This contract is a fork of [NotSafeMoon](https://bscscan.com/token/0x337e35Ed5B38D5C7Ec9F8d7cF78fe7F43d7DEC6F). I'm using Remix and trying to deploy to testnet. I can't tell what I should make "payable".

I've tried looking at similar questions in the forum but has so far hasn't figured it out. thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi there. Are you passing a value of ETH on deployment? (Which won't work because the constructor isn't payable.)

Comment: Is 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E a valid router address?